# How to use height attribute in code igniter for form_multiselect?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have to change the default height for multi select in code igniter , but I am unable to change it , here is my code...

```
echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),'id="RequistionNo"' , 'required="true"', 'Height="200px"' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with style tag like below.

```
echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),array('size'=>8,'id'=>"Re‌​quistionNo",'require‌​d'=>"true") );
```

Comment: I tried this but not working , sorry and thanks for your suggestion @ Saurabh

Comment: You can try with size attribute for your custom attribute.like echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),'id="RequistionNo"' , 'required="true"', 'size="8"' );

Comment: @saravanakumarkandasami Try this echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),array('size'=>8,'id'=>"RequistionNo",'required'=>"true")  ); I check this it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your code, you haven't used form_multiselect function correctly. Below is the syntax for the same:

```
 form_multiselect([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[, $extra = '']]]])
```

So your code should look like:

```
echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),'id="RequistionNo" required="true" height="200px"');
```

Let me know if it still does not works for you.

Comment: Can you show me what HTML code is being generated using this helper function. Check using view source in you browser

Comment: <div class="col-md-3">
   <label>Requistion No</label>
      <?php        
         $options = array("0"=>'Selected Requisition Numbers'); 
         if(!empty($ReqList))
      {
      foreach ($ReqList as $SID):
      
         $options[$SID->ReqNo] = $SID->ReqNo ."-". $SID->ReqBy;
                           $ReqType = $SID->ReqType;
      endforeach;
      }        
echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),'id="RequistionNo" ,required="true"' );
?>       
</div>

Comment: You are not using what I have provided to you, also source code you provided does not belongs to executed output for this line.

Please use this code
echo form_multiselect('RequistionNo', $options,set_value('RequistionNo'),'id="RequistionNo" required="true" height="200px"');

-----------After execution provide generated html (Not written PHP code)

Comment: Its should be under each option, not for select.